# Refresh a label on WPF page

Tags: wpf, xaml, refresh

How do I refresh a label on WPF page.

Basically the label displays how many agents there are, so when I put all the users details in and click Create User. When I click the button, I need the label to refresh on that page.

I have tried setting the content to null and then reloading the data.

```
int NumberOfAgents = _Users.Where(w => w.RoleID == _Role.FirstOrDefault(a => a.RoleType == "Agent").RoleID).ToList().Count();

lblCountAgent.Content=null 
lblCountAgents.Content = NumberOfAgents.ToString();
```

But this does not seem to work.

If anyone could help me out on this that would be great.

Comment: That should work.  In debug what is the value of NumberOfAgents?

Comment: Are you sure that `NumberOfAgents` > 0?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Have you verified that the NumberOfAgents variable is correct?

Comment: Just use data binding. BTW, there's a trailing S letter when setting the value.

Comment: @Blam The value will be equal to what I already have, so I wont add the user that I just added if you get me, I don't know whether I need to instantiate the list again, as I have only done it at the top of my form.

Comment: @Ben, You asked how to make your label refresh. If the value is the same, what would change on the UI?

Comment: @LordTakkera The value should change when I add a new user, it should refresh the label.

Comment: So, to reask everyone's question, is the value changing correctly if you look at it in the debugger? Your query is likely the location of the bug.

Comment: So the value should change.  For the 5th time now is the value changing?  In debug what is the value of NumberOfAgents?  Do you know how to debug?

Comment: @LordTakkera No its not changing correctly on the debugger

Comment: @Blam Yes, the value is not changing. If it was it would work.

Comment: Then the query is your problem. If you constantly are getting "0" then its likely that no users with RoleType == "Agent" exist. Also, you don't need the "ToList", .Count will work on any IEnumerable.

Comment: If the value of NumberOfAgents does not change then the value displayed in lblCountAgents.Content will not change.  The stated question is how to refresh a label.  If you refresh with the same value then the value will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems ok, NumberOfAgents probably isn't what you think it is and should be checked in the debugger.

On a side note, please don't code this way in WPF. You shouldn't be programmatically setting properties like "Content", and most of the time you shouldn't be programmatically setting properties at all.

Instead, the "Content" property of your label should be bound to a "NumberOfAgents" property in a ViewModel class that can then be set (raising PropertyChanged) when you create a user. This will propagate through the UI via the binding system. Here is an MSDN [tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-MVVM-Examples-fb8c409f) on how to set up MVVM with WPF.